# Showing taxonomies in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have a Wordpress site with three custom taxonomies. They're configured and working, with some posts marked with each, and want to run code related to them. As per the documentation, if the custom taxonomies are cats, dogs and trees, and I want to run php about cats, after lots of trying and going up and down over the documentation, I think I should create a template and call it "taxonomy-cats.php":

> taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php: For example, if the taxonomy is named “sometax,” WordPress would look for a file named taxonomy-sometax.php

But I still don't get something: the docs say "wordpres would look for". Why would WP look for it and not other? I suppose I at least have to tell it what or when to search for it. How or where do I tell WP to look for it?

```
<?php /* Template Name: Taxonomy cats */
get_header(); ?>

<h1>Hello world</h1>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As a template, I've found I can add it in the administration as an attribute to a post, but then when I enter that page if I try to get the id of the taxonomy, I get the id of the post.

Comment: TL;DR Install (and enable) mod_rewrite in your server and point the browser to /taxonomy/name-of-the-taxonomy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress uses a loop to display posts. Wherever you are, most of time, the loop is being used.

> The Loop is PHP code used by WordPress to display posts. Using The
> Loop, WordPress processes each post to be displayed on the current
> page, and formats it according to how it matches specified criteria
> within The Loop tags. Any HTML or PHP code in the Loop will be
> processed on each post.

*Source @ https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop*

Wordpress is also based on a template hierarchy system. With the exception of the basic index.php template file, you can choose whether you want to implement a particular template file or not.

> WordPress uses the query string to decide which template or set of
> templates should be used to display the page. The query string is
> information that is contained in the link to each part of your
> website.

[You can take a look at this image to have a visual understanding of the Wordpress templates hierarchy.](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png)

*Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/*

In your case when displaying the `dogs` taxonomy, Wordpress look for the following files in that order: `taxonomy-pets-dogs.php`if this template doesn't exist it move on to look for pets `taxonomy-pets.php`, if it doesn't exist it moves on to `taxonomy.php`... etc
(Where `pets` is the name of your taxonomy and `dogs` is a term inside that taxonomy)

Specifying `taxonomy-pets-dogs.php` enables you to create a custom template for that specific term. `cats` wont have the same template as `dogs` exept if both are using `taxonomy.php` or `taxonomy-pets.php` and if no specific templates exist.

But in any case `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` or `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` will always use the loop to display posts and terms. Like any other template.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   echo the_title().'<br/>';
endwhile; else :
   echo 'No posts found!';
endif; ?>
```

Comment: Just for clarification, **this is not what I am asking**. As I tell in the question, I've already read all that documentation, and, when I put "the loop" or whatever WP code, I just get the post instead of the taxonomy.

Comment: "**WordPress uses the query string**" that's interesting. How would a taxonomy query string look like?

Comment: It's not "instead", the `taxonomy.php` is an archive page, an archive page is made to display posts against terms from that taxonomy, but it is not made by default to display terms. You can adapt your template to display them. Is that what you're trying to do ?

Comment: **Why would WP look for it and not other?** Wordpres would look for the right template upon request from the user, when you look for something like that: `domain.com/pets/dog/` Wordpress look for the following files in that order: `taxonomy-pets-dogs.php` if this template doesn't exist it move on to look for `taxonomy-pets.php`, if it doesn't exist it moves on to `taxonomy.php`... etc and so on.

Comment: If I still didn't managed to answer your question, you might want to reformulate.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it says so in the documentation. Thanks for the clues, right now researching whats the real url behind /pets/dog/ .

Comment: Still don't know the real url. After looking at the .htaccess from live Wordpress installations, they're so simple that probably WP is reading the URL and doing pattern matching internally, so I won't waste more of your time: just installed mod_rewrite in this dev server, and its works. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I don't think i understand what you mean by `still don't know the real url`